# laurent series of $\frac{z^2-2z+2}{(z-1)(z^2-2z-3)}$ around $z-1$ for $0<|z-1|<2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the Laurent series of $L=\frac{z^2-2z+2}{(z-1)(z^2-2z+3}$ around $(z-1)$

Here, I used the fact that 
$L=\frac{5}{8(z-3)}+\frac{5}{8(z+1)}-\frac{1}{4(z-1)}$

When $|z-1|<2$, we have

$L=\frac{-1}{4(z-1)}+\frac{5}{8} \frac{1}{(z-1)-2} +\frac{5}{8( (z-1)+2)}$

$=\frac{-1}{4(z-1)} +\frac{5}{-16}\frac{1}{1- \frac{(z-1)}{2}} + \frac{5}{16} \frac{1}{1+ \frac{(z-1)}{2}} =-\frac{1}{4(z-1)}+ \frac{5}{16} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(z-1)^k}{2^k}(-1+(-1)^k)=-\frac{1}{4(z-1)}+\frac{5}{16} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-1)^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1}} (-2)$

However,in my book, Elements d'analyse complexe by Real Gelinas,
the answer for 0<|z-1|<2 is

$\frac{-1}{4} (z-1 + \frac{1}{z-1} )\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{z-1}{2n})^{2n}.$

Hence, I am missing a term.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Note that the numerator $\equiv z^2-2z +2=(z^2-2z+1)+1=(z-1)^2+1\neq (z-1)^2$.

Comment: silly me. OK i will make these changes

Comment: Another cool Laurent question ! Check my analysis down below !

Comment: @Rebellos your answer is useful. I edited my question with the right numerator, but I still can't find where my mistake is

Comment: In your third step, your fractions in the denominator are wrong. The $z-1$ expressions shouldn't be in the numerators.

Comment: why not? @Rebellos

Comment: @abc $(z-1)-2 = (z-1)(1- \frac{2}{z-1})$

Comment: But $(z-1)-2 = -2 ( 1- \frac{z-1}{2})$ also. Why can't I use this? @Rebellos

Comment: @abc It's not wrong, you're right, froma quick eye I could say you made a misscalculation on the double sums.

Comment: I did not get any double sums in my calculations, only added the values of my two sums

Comment: @abc It doesn't work like that, check for example the sum of that : 

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x^n) +  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  (-1)^n x^n \neq  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  ((-1)^n x^n + x^n) $$

Links : [Initial Sum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5Einf+(x%5En)+%2B++%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7Binf%7D++(-1)%5En+x%5En) - [Wrong Sum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7Binf%7D++((-1)%5En+*+x%5En+%2B+x%5En))

Comment: No, they are both equal. Note that by putting everything on the same denominator, you get $1/(x+1) + 1/(1-x) = -2/(x+1)(x-1). $

Answer (score 3):

**Note :** Since you've made a mistake in your expressions while solving (the one mentioned in the comments) I'll go over a more straight-forward and common approach, by demonstrating its all steps.

The trick is to form the expression that is asked to form the Laurent series around, which in that specific case is : $z-1$. This is what I'm going to demonstrate down below :

$$L(z) = \frac{z^2-2z+2}{(z-1)(z^2-2z-3)}= \frac{(z-1)^2+1}{(z-1)(z+1)(z-3)}$$

$$=$$
$$\frac{(z-1)^2+1}{(z-1)(z-1+2)(z-1-2)} = \frac{(z-1)^2+2}{(z-1)(z-1)(z-1)(1+\frac{2}{z-1})(1-\frac{2}{z-1})}$$

$$=$$

$$\frac{(z-1)^2+1}{(z-1)^3(1+\frac{2}{z-1})(1-\frac{2}{z-1})}$$

Now, we know the following simple geometric series :

$$\frac{1}{1-w}\sum_{n=0}^\infty w^n \quad |w|<1$$

$$\frac{1}{1+w} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nw^n \quad |w|<1$$

Applying these for $\frac{2}{z-1} = w$ :

$$[(z-1)^2+1] \frac{1}{(z-1)^3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n2^n(z-1)^{-n}\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n(z-1)^{-n} $$

$$=$$

$$\bigg[\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{(z-1)^3}\bigg]\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n2^n(z-1)^{-n}\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n(z-1)^{-n} $$

Can you now combine all of these into one expression and yield your results ? For the relation of $|z-1|$ given, it's easy to spot since you'd want $|\frac{2}{z-1}| < 1$ and on the same time $z-1\neq 0$ which means given your first condition that $|z-1| > 0$. Combining these you get : $0<|z-1|<2$.